# Having troubles adding 3 layouts to 1 listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a ListView and custom adapter and trying to get my data to be displayed inside of the ListView. I have three layouts to show the data but not able to get the data to display. I am having the hardcoded text of GROCERY being populated in each row for the list view not the three layouts I want and their respected data.

CustomAdapter

```
public class CompleteEReceiptDisplay extends Activity implements AppCompatCallback {
private AppCompatDelegate delegate;
Toolbar mToolbar;
private ImageView menuBtn, backBtn;
ListView mFullReceiptLV;
List<EreceiptPojo> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private RelativeLayout mFullItemLine;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Show Toolbar without extending AppCompatActivity
    delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this);
    delegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    delegate.setContentView(R.layout.complete_ereceipt_display);
    delegate.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mFullReceiptLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fullEReceiptListView);
    menuBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menuBtn);
    backBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icnBackArrow);
    menuBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    backBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    parseList();
    FullEReceiptAdapter mFullAdapter = new FullEReceiptAdapter(this);
    mFullReceiptLV.setAdapter(mFullAdapter);
}

private void parseList() {
    String itemCateg = "", itemPrice = "", itemDesc = "";
    HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>> mHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<LineDetail> mLineDetailList = MainActivity.mCompleteReceiptData.getLineDetailList().getLineDetail();

    for (int i = 0; i < mLineDetailList.size(); i++) {
        LineDetail lineDetail = mLineDetailList.get(i);

        itemPrice = lineDetail.getPrice();
        List<Item> itemList = lineDetail.getCustomAttributes().getItem();
        for (int j = 0; j < itemList.size(); j++) {
            Item it = itemList.get(j);
            if (it.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("PrintCategory")) {
                itemCateg = it.getValue();
            } else if (it.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("ItemDescription")) {
                itemDesc = it.getValue();
            }
        }
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put(itemDesc, itemPrice);


        if (mHashMap.containsKey(itemCateg)) {
            mHashMap.get(itemCateg).add(hm);
        } else {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> mMap = new ArrayList<>();
            mMap.add(hm);
            mHashMap.put(itemCateg, mMap);
        }
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>> entry : mHashMap.entrySet()) {
        itemCateg = entry.getKey();
        double mDouble = 0.00;

        EreceiptPojo ereceiptPojo = new EreceiptPojo();
        ereceiptPojo.setItemName(itemCateg);
        ereceiptPojo.setCategory(true);
        ereceiptPojo.setSubTotal(false);
        mainList.add(ereceiptPojo);

        List<HashMap<String, String>> dummyList = entry.getValue();
        for (int i = 0; i < dummyList.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm1 = new HashMap<>();
            hm1 = dummyList.get(i);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 : hm1.entrySet()) {
                EreceiptPojo ereceiptPojo1 = new EreceiptPojo();
                ereceiptPojo.setItemName(entry1.getKey());
                ereceiptPojo1.setItemPrice(entry1.getValue());
                ereceiptPojo1.setCategory(false);
                ereceiptPojo1.setSubTotal(false);
                mainList.add(ereceiptPojo1);

                mDouble = mDouble + Double.parseDouble(entry1.getValue());

            }
        }
        EreceiptPojo mEreceiptPojo = new EreceiptPojo();
        mEreceiptPojo.setItemPrice(String.valueOf(mDouble));
        mEreceiptPojo.setCategory(false);
        mEreceiptPojo.setSubTotal(true);
        mainList.add(mEreceiptPojo);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {

}

@Override
public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public ActionMode onWindowStartingSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
    return null;
}

public class FullEReceiptAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_CATEGORY = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_ITEM_NAME = 2;
    public static final int TYPE_PRICE = 3;

    public FullEReceiptAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mainList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mainList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        EreceiptPojo obj = mainList.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int layout_type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.full_receipt_category_header, parent, false);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (obj.isCategory() == true) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mHeaderView = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.full_receipt_category_header_layout);
        }
        if (obj.isSubTotal() == true) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mLineItemsTotalPrice = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subTotalView);
        }

        if(obj.getItemName().length() > 0 && obj.getItemPrice().length() > 0) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mLineItemName = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.full_receipt_item_line);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout mHeaderView;
    public TextView mLineItemName;
    public TextView mLineItemPrice;
    public LinearLayout mLineItemsTotalPrice;
}
```

}

Three layouts I am tryign to attach to the adapter. 
The first layout is the one that keeps repeating within the ListView.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/full_receipt_category_header_layout">

        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/full_receipt_category_header_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="GROCERY"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLineItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CUB SPLT TOP WHEAT"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLineItemPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$1.70*"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/subTotalView">

        <View
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorGrey"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCategoryTotalPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:text="$5.70"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>

The layout that contains the ListView

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_receipt"
        android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bannerReceiptLogo"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img_logo_receipt_cub"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bannerAddressHeader"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/storeHeader"
            android:layout_below="@id/bannerReceiptLogo"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/fullEReceiptListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/bannerAddressHeader"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working as I had to inflate each layout inside my adapter for each position within the view. The chances are in the getView().

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        EreceiptPojo obj = mainList.get(position);
        TaxDetail taxDetail = new TaxDetail();
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (obj.isCategory()) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.full_receipt_category_header, parent, false);
            TextView mCat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.full_receipt_category_header_text);
            mCat.setText(obj.getItemName());

        }
        else if (obj.isSubTotal()) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.full_receipt_category_total, parent, false);
            TextView subTotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoryTotalPrice);
            subTotal.setText(obj.getItemPrice());
        }
       else if(!obj.isSubTotal() && !obj.isCategory()){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.full_receipt_item_line, parent, false);
            TextView itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLineItem);
            TextView itemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLineItemPrice);
            itemName.setText(obj.getItemName());
            itemPrice.setText(obj.getItemPrice());
        } else {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tax_layout, parent, false);
            TextView mFinalSubtotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTotalFinal);
            TextView mTotalTax = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTaxTotal);
            TextView mPurchaseTotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCompleteTotalNumber);
            for(int i = 0; i < obj.getItemPrice().length(); i++) {
                String subTotalFinal = obj.setItemPrice(i);
            }
```